# Vimeo Thumbnails for private video in PHP

Tags: php, curl, thumbnails, vimeo, oembed

I have tried every single answer on this forum and couldn't get a proper working code. So I am posting this again.
I want to get the thumbnail of private and hidden Videos from Vimeo. I also have an access token generated which I tried to use with the solutions provided for the old questions which also didn't work.

I tried this code

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/531126552/access_token
```

Also tried using cURL

```
curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'Authorization: bearer {access_token}',
        'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
    )
);

curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl_h);
```

The response for above cURL code is this:

```
{"error":"Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners.","link":null,"developer_message":"No user credentials were provided.","error_code":8003}
```

Please suggest me a way to do this or help me find where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnails can be accessed by the thumbnail_url in JSON data provided by Oembed API
sample :
[https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/{video_id}/](https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/%7Bvideo_id%7D/)

Comment: Not when it is a private video.  You have to send the referer header..which is what I am trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for public videos.  I know you asked about private, so I am going to ask, if you ever figured it out...ping me. Trying to figure out the same.

For others, here is the public solution.  It is the private videos that it fails on.

```
function mmd_get_vimeo_info( $video_id ) 
 {
  // https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/
  
  $VimeoConnectLink        = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/" . $video_id ;   
  $request                 = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw($VimeoConnectLink));
  if ('error' == $request || is_wp_error($request))
    return ""; 
    
  $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
  if ('error' == $response || is_wp_error($response))
    return ""; 
    
  $video_array = json_decode( $response, true );
    
// Looking for [title], [thumbnail_url] [duration]
  return $video_array;
 }
```

But it can fail with domain privacy in place.